# Draw line with two points and place it on geometry

Tags: math, three.js, geometry, webgl

I have a plane geometry and I want to draw line between two points

[image: https://ibb.co/douynJ]

but I want to make it "laying" on mesh like this
[image]

How can I find appropriate triangles and calculate Y for line point?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48324407/how-to-project-a-rectangle-onto-a-mesh-terrain-object-for-use-as-a-select-marqu

Comment: As a work-around, you could add a texture to your mesh and draw a line on your texture.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on what you want the line to do. If you want to draw the shortest path between two points, that's a very complicated problem - google "shortest path on mesh".

If you want a 2D line projected vertically onto the mesh, that's much easier to do. It is not the same as a shortest path. Think of a tall mountain - shortest path between two points on its base probably goes around the mountain, instead of over it.

Assuming you simply mutated the points on your plane geometry with your height data, you would have to trace a line between your two points, figure out which 2D triangles it crosses, and split the line accordingly. It's pretty straightforward but will take a good bit of code to get right.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It basically just says "Solutions exist". If you're going to post an answer please actually post a solution rather than just say it's possible. People asking for help are unlikely to be able to act on an answer like this.